# How can I cleanup the IPC message-queue?

Tags: c, ipc, message-queue

I am using `msgget()` function in my IPC based application. How can I clean up the queue filled up with old message queues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To delete a queue, use the following command:

```
msgctl(msgQID, IPC_RMID, NULL);
```

[SYSTEM CALL: msgctl()](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node36.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the message queue attribute for O_NONBLOCK by using **mq_setattr**.
Then empty the queue by reading all of the messages, until the returned value indicates the queue is empty.
Now set back the old attributes.

This method is not a run time optimized, but it avoids the need to close and open the message queue.

Answer (score 1):

A work around is to increase **MSGMNI** System wide maximum number of message queues: policy dependent (on Linux, this limit can be read and modified via **/proc/sys/kernel/msgmni**).

Answer (score 0):

These persistent resource allocation issues (there's a similar one with shared memory) are why the System V APIs are generally considered deprecated.  In this case, have you considered using a unix domain socket or FIFO instead of a message queue?  Those appear in the filesystem, and can be "cleaned up" when no longer used with tools like rm.